# word for number of matches between two soccer clubs

Tags: single-word-requests

I need single word for number of matches between two soccer clubs in one season / group stage of tournament.

For example, in English Premier League every team is playing each other team twice (home and away).

I know that there should be sentence for example, but this should be one word for table data.

So for example this is how would I use it:

> - League name: Premier League
> - Tier: 1
> - Season: 2017. / 2018.
> - Number of teams: 20
> - _______: 2
> - Country: England

Something like "Matches between each other:".

Ty

Comment: ***Faceoffs***?

Comment: @DanBron Would face-off be more for ice-hockey than soccer/football? Face-Offs sounds slightly Am-Eng to me

Comment: "Soccer" sounds slightly Am-Eng to me...

Comment: 'Fixtures '  - ? It is British enough.

Comment: I believe I've seen *encounters* being used this way...

Comment: Scotland doesn't have a simple number here! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Premiership *... a "split" format ... to prevent the need for a 44-game schedule, based on playing each other four times. ... considered to be too high ...  divided into two phases. During the first phase, each club plays three games against every other team, ... After this first phase of matches, by which time all clubs have played 33 games, the league splits into a 'top six' and a 'bottom six'. Each club then plays a further five matches, one against each of the other five teams in their own section.*

Comment: Seems as if you need to say *Each team place every other team home and away*.

Comment: @WS2 In most leagues indeed that is true but the point is in a few leagues they only play each other once, in others they play 4 times (2 home and 2 away) and there are other variants too.

Comment: @k1eran So what exactly is it you want to know?

Comment: @WS2 I was just pointing out that they may not in fact play each other home and away; at least that's my interpretation of the OP's question.

Comment: @k1eran I'm still no nearer understanding what the OP wants to know. What's wrong with "matches between one another"?

Comment: Baseball has “split series” between 2 teams where “split”=splitting the home advantage between each team (eg 2 teams play “a 4-game ‘split’ series," w/2 games on 1 team's field, then 2 games on the other's), but a “series” (split or otherwise) usually means the games are played back-to-back. If your teams do play each other in consecutive matches you could say that each team has one “2-match ‘split’ series” w/each other per season & if not, maybe you could even try extending “split” to also mean “not back-to-back": “Type of series"="Two-match split”//”Number of series between each team"="1.”

Answer (score 1):

**Number of head-to-heads**
or
**Head-to-head fixtures**
or perhaps even simply
**Head-to-heads**

For example, from http://www.soccerpunter.com/soccer-statistics :

> Head to Head (H2H) Statistics.
>   Compare two teams to find out who is stronger based on their past match results.

The main English Premiership site which has [a web page](https://www.premierleague.com/stats/head-to-head) for generating head-to-head statistics.

From the the [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4323626/Real-Madrid-vs-Bayern-Champions-League-head-heads.html):

> Bayern Munich vs Real Madrid
>   [...]
>   Head to head:  Played 22: Real 9 Draw 2 Bayern 11

Googling, *football head to head* gives about 130 million results so it seems idiomatic.

Comment: This refers to such matches, not the number of such matches.